# Put DOMNodeList to a string in PHP, to edit it later

Tags: php, dom

I have extracted all links of a page using `PHP` and `DOM`. Now I want to edit the result. I thought of putting the result in a variable and then using the str_replace function to edit it, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is it possible to put the `DOM` result to a string?
My code:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($homepage);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
echo str_replace("text1","text2",$link->getAttribute('href'));
}
?>
```

Comment: Which ones??  Can you show code?

Comment: I didn't include it because I want to put the links into a string. The rest I can do it myself

Comment: Yeah, but if I put `echo $link...href')` outside the foreach loop it prints a line of text from the html (not the links)

Comment: Or if I put it inside the `str_replace` function

Comment: Even if it is inside `foreach` but into `str_replace` it doesn't work

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: Magically it worked now. I forgot a `)`